# How to check whether the date is in past or not?and How to get difference between two dates? by input tag type date and type time

Tags: javascript, date

Restaurant app booking a table feature.

Date input by `<input type="date"> and <input type="time">`

What I need.

1.How check whether the given/input date and time is in past or not.If past not valid,if future valid for booking.

2.How to get difference between two dates and times.So that I can show time left for booked table,and the user is allowed to get a table within the booked date and time mentioned.(may be by `setInterval()`)

HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="tdatetime">
      <tr><td>Select Date</td><td>Select Time</td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="date" id="bdate"></td><td><input type="time" id="btime"></td></tr>
    </table>

<input type="button" id="bdtbtn" onclick="getbdtRL(this)" value="Book Now"></input>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS

```
function getbdtRL(bookbtn)
        {
        var bdate=$("#bdate").val();
            var btime=$("#btime").val();

            var now = new Date();
                    var selectedDate=new Date(bdate);
                    var selectedTime=new Date(btime);
                    alert(btime);//returns for example- 2:00
                    alert(selectedTime);//returns Invalid Date
                    alert(selectedTime.toString());//returns Invalid Date
                    alert(selectedTime.toTimeString());//returns Invalid Date
                    alert(selectedTime.toDateString());//returns Invalid Date

            //Date check is working
            if(selectedDate<now)
                    {
                    alert("Selected Date is in Past");
                    }
                    else if(selectedDate>now)
                    {
                        alert("Selected Date is in Future");    
                    }
                    else if(selectedDate==now)
                    {
                        alert("Selected Date is in Present");   
                    }

            //Time Check is not working by selectedTime
                    if(selectedTime<now)
                    {
                    alert("Selected Time is in Past");
                    }
                    else if(selectedTime>now)
                    {
                        alert("Selected Time is in Future");    
                    }
                    else if(selectedTime==now)
                    {
                        alert("Selected Time is in Present");   
                    }

        //Time Check is not working by btime
                    if(btime<now)
                    {
                    alert("Selected Time is in Past");
                    }
                    else if(btime>now)
                    {
                        alert("Selected Time is in Future");    
                    }
                    else if(btime==now)
                    {
                        alert("Selected Time is in Present");   
                    }
    }


    //Date and Time Difference not working
    var date=new Date();
                var tempdate="2015-05-01";
                var d1 = date;//tempdate;//
                //alert("current date d1="+d1);
                var d2 = RLArrBookDateSender;//receiving from db2 database data type is time which is already booked
                //alert("booked date d2="+d2);
                var DateDiff = {

                        inDays: function(d1,d2) {
                            var t2 = d2.getTime();
                            var t1 = d1.getTime();

                            return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
                        }
                };
                alert("diff="+DateDiff.inDays(d1,d2));//no alert executes
```

Comment: `var selectedTime=new Date(btime);` How can time return you DATE??

Comment: I suggest you to use `momentjs` library. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: May be I am Wrong.I am new in Javascript especially in date time stuffs.So what to do to check time validation past or future considering on same date.

Comment: Got Solution:var validFutureDate = new Date(bdate + ' ' + btime); alert("validFutureDate="+validFutureDate);//returns Fri May 15 2015 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)//means 2day at 6:00 PM.It joins both date and time which is good.var diff = validFutureDate.getTime() - now.getTime();alert("validFutureDate.getTime()="+validFutureDate.getTime());var dayDiff = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60*24)); var hourDiff = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60)); alert("dayDiff="+dayDiff);//returns 0 alert("hourDiff="+hourDiff);//returns 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if you were looking for more to the answer...but if the following is right then it should make sense...

(It's late, but i believe the logic is right...)

To compare dates:

```
var now = new Date();
var selectDate = new Date(bdate);
var diff = now.getTime() - selectDate.getTime();
if(diff > 0 || diff == 0) {
  // selected date is in the past or is our current time 
  // (which should be tough to match down to milliseconds)
}
else if (diff < 0) {
  // selected date has not past
}
```

To get the time left until a future date:

```
var now = new Date();
var validFutureDate = new Date(bdate);
var diff = validFutureDate.getTime() - now.getTime(); // in milliseconds
var dayDiff = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: How can from bdate I can get the time left?bdate is for date e.g. 2015/05/16 and btime is for time e.g. 5:00 PM.and diff should be like this first diff between dates 2015/05/15 and 2015/05/16 is 1 day,then it checks for time diff 1:00 PM and 5:00 PM is 4 hours 0 minutes 0 secs.

Comment: my mistake. i forgot to add in the .getTime() functions

Comment: .getTime function converts the date/time into milliseconds. This should give you the means to write up the conversion code necessary to find the difference (which is the time left)

Comment: That means no use of btime booked time hh:mm AM/PM?Then may be logically the calculation will go wrong.

Comment: I see what you are saying. why don't you preformat btime to be for example: var bdate= new Date("May 16, 2015 11:13:00"); 

By doing so, we will be able to do the computation using the basic code above? But you will need to do a modulus operation on diff in order to find the milliseconds remainder in the conversion to days, then convert that to hours, mins, secs

Comment: alert(new Date( bdate.value + ' ' + btime.value ));//returns "Invalid date"

Comment: You will need to preformat it to follow the format required  by the constructors: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00") or new Date(99,5,24,11,33,30,0); (where the constructor is new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds))

Comment: You can potentially change your html input types to retrieve a datatime-local format which may be easier to correctly format. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: How to do?What are the steps involved?

Comment: As you have mentioned var dayDiff = parseInt(diff/(60*60*60*24));.I think it will be var dayDiff = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60*24));//millisecond to seconds divide by 1000 then minutes *60 then hours *60 then days *24

Comment: var validFutureDate = new Date(bdate + ' ' + btime);
alert("validFutureDate="+validFutureDate);//returns Fri May 15 2015 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)//means 2day at 6:00 PM.It joins both date and time which is good.var diff = validFutureDate.getTime() - now.getTime();alert("validFutureDate.getTime()="+validFutureDate.getTime());var dayDiff = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60*24));
var hourDiff = parseInt(diff/(1000*60*60));
alert("dayDiff="+dayDiff);//returns 0
alert("hourDiff="+hourDiff);//returns 2

Comment: You are right on the conversion from sec to milliseconds. One of the great things about coding from the phone and so late. Additionally, that last comment of yours looks like you're onto the correct logic ☺! Is it working out for you now?

Comment: One more help please...I stored btime in a ibm db2 database in BookTime column/attribute with time data type,it shows in db2 control center e.g. 01:02:00 PM but when I retrieve from database and store it in a variable and display it .It shows as "13:02:00".So how to convert 24 hrs to 12 hrs with AM/PM where hr,min,sec are joined or as if as a string.SO either extracting by ":" separator which is a long process or is there any build in function???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77986/discussion-between-ejsd1989-and-sphakrrokr-subhrojit).

Comment: I got it:var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
hh = ((h + 11) % 12 + 1);
ampm = (h >= 12)? 'PM' : 'AM';
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
var DRestaurantRL2 = $("#tDetailsCurrentDateTime");
var DAppndRL21=$('<br><tr><td><b>Current TIME:</b></td><td>'+hh+":"+m+":"+s+' '+ampm+'</td></tr>');
DRestaurantRL2.empty().append(DAppndRL21);

function checkTime(i) {
if (i<10) {i = "0" + i}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value from the DOM element, new Date only accepts a String or a Number or a series of Numbers, not DOM elements. Try entering a value in your Date and Time fields and entering the below code into the console.

```
alert( new Date( bdate.value + ' ' + btime.value ) - new Date > 0? 'future' : 'past');
```

Comment: It always says past even if I give future date and time.alert(new Date( bdate.value + ' ' + btime.value ) - new Date);//returns me NaN

Comment: that's because you still have your old code running

Comment: This one is working for me in ibm worklight console by omit .value .alert( new Date( bdate + ' ' + btime ) - new Date > 0? 'future' : 'past');

Answer (score 0):

You can check it that way: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/gt4tqca9/

```
var date_in_future = new Date("2015-10-20"),
    date_in_past = new Date("2014-05-15");

function check (date) {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        target = date.getTime();

    if (target <= now) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function diff (date) {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        target = date.getTime();

    return now - target;
}

console.log(date_in_future);
console.log(date_in_past);

console.log("future date? " + check(date_in_future));
console.log("future date? " + check(date_in_past));

console.log("diff: " + diff(date_in_future));
console.log("diff: " + diff(date_in_past));
```